# How to get Choose File And Another button on the same line?

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I am using the ng-file-upload directive to upload files. I have a scenario where the number of files to be uploaded is decided dynamically. Also I have created have a slightly deviated scenario form the standard where Upload and Submit buttons are separate and needless to say do different actions.
Now what I want to do is get the **Choose File ie. `<input type="file">`** and **Upload Button** on the same line but I have not been able to do so.

**My Relevant Markup:**

```
<input type="file" ngf-select ng-model="input.value" name="{{input.name}}" ngf-model-invalid="errorFile" required>
<button type="button" ng-show="input.value !== null" ng-click="uploadFile(input.value, $index)">Upload File</button>
<span ng-show="input.value.progress >= 0">
    <div class="progress" style="width:{{input.value.progress}}%" ng-bind="input.value.progress + '%'"></div>
</span>
```

What can I do in this case?

Comment: do you want to click that button and open file input?

Comment: No, another button is used to call the `uploadFile()` which uploads the file instead of using Submit button for uploading the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to float-right the button ([see here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)) 
Like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
  div.inline { float:left; }
  .clearBoth { clear:both; }
</style>
```

and at the end clear the float with class clearBoth

Comment: I can't open the link